# Submit form using Ajax php file through JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to submit a normal html form to a database:

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="productForm" onsubmit="return submitProduct(this);">
```

With the above line I call the method "submitProduct". The code for this method is:

```
function submitProduct(form_ele) {
  var values = $(form_ele).serialize();
  $.ajax({
        url: "forms/ajax/admin/form_modifications.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Success");
        },
    });
}
```

So with the above code I should be able to go in "form_modifications.php" script right? 
I haven't managed to get the "data: values" from the form yet (which it should be fine once I figure out how to go there)

In form_modifications.php I have the following (I wanted just to test it):

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../..");
require_once("config/config.inc.php");
require_once("init.php");

$sql_test = "INSERT INTO ps_test_product (name) VALUES ('test');";
Db::getInstance()->query($sql_test);
```

I can't understand why but it doesn't work. The query is not executed and I can't find what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does the alert show up? Does the form submit (there doesn't seem to be anything stopping it?). Can you return something from PHP to the success handler? It's all about figuring out exactly where the problem is !

Comment: For starters prevent the default submit and then use browser dev tools console and network to do basic debugging. Inspect actual request for clues

Comment: in that case, it could be require file, did u try just going straight to the form_modification.php. Does it show any errors?

Comment: thanks for the replies. @madi I did try that and everything's fine with db connection. adeneo No alert is shown up. charlietfl could you please explain what you mean by default submit? I am trying to find more ways to test what it is going wrong.

Comment: did u even check that the ajax is being executed using ur chrome inspect?

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting it could be that the ajax is not fired since you have said that the direct access to form_modification.php is working fine. So I can only advise you on what you should do to debug. From there you will get more clues.

Step 1: Dun use html inline onsubmit, so remove that code

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="productForm">
 ...............
</form>
```

Step 2: Change Javascript code and bind submit event using jquery

```
    $( "#productForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
      console.log("I am running");
       var values = $(this).serialize();
       $.ajax({
             url: "forms/ajax/admin/form_modifications.php",
             type: "post",
             data: values,
             success: function (response) {
                  alert("Success");
             },
        });
    });
```

Step 3: Use google chrome and click inspect element and click network tab. Now click the form submit at browser by filling in whatever inputs and see if the post request is being pushed.

Step 4: Click console tab at the inspect element and see if "I am running" is being printed out. If it does, the submit event is working.